# Show that $M\cap N$ is the set of all scalar multiples of vector $a$ in $M \cap N$.

Tags: vector-spaces

> Show that the set of triples $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$ is a subspace $M$. If $N$ is the similar subspace $\{x : x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$, find a nonzero vector $a$ in $M\cap N$. Show that $M\cap N$ is the set $\{xa : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of all scalar multiples of $a$.

Suppose $y \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then

\begin{align}
(x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3) + (y_1 - y_2 + 2y_3) &= 0 \\
x_1 + y_1 - x_2 - y_2 + 2(x_3 + y_3) &= 0
\end{align}

For a scalar value $c$,

\begin{align}
c(x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3) &= 0c \\
cx_1 - cx_2 + 2cx_3 &= 0
\end{align}

Thus the set is a subspace of $M$.

If $N$ is a similar subspace $\{ x : x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$ then the intersection $M\cap N$ is the set of triples $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$. Here I am unsure what *"find a nonzero vector $a$ in $M\cap N$* means. My initial thoughts are that a nonzero vector is a vector such that $x_1, x_2, x_3 \neq 0$, but not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nonzero vector is simply a vector that is not the zero vector. That is, it is not the case that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$. Notice that this is not the same as $x_1, x_2, x_3 \neq 0$, as, for example, the vector $(1,0,0)$ is nonzero.

The set $M \cap N$ is the set of triples $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ such that both of the following happen:

$x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$ (that is, the vector is in $M$)

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ (that is, the vector is in $N$)

This is a system of two equations that can easily be shown to be equivalent to the system:

$x_1 + \frac 3 2 x_3 = 0$

$x_1 + 3 x_2 = 0$

Now the following fact becomes obvious: a vector from the space $M \cap N$ is uniquely determined by its first component. That is, knowing its first component we can determine the other two, and for any $x_1$ we can find a vector of $M \cap N$ such that its first component is $x_1$.

Taking this a step further, we come to the conclusion (solving the previous equations for $x_2$ and $x_3$) that the vectors of $M \cap N$ are precisely those of the form:

$(x_1, -\frac 1 3 x_1, - \frac 2 3 x_1)$, or, equivalently, $x_1 (1, -\frac 1 3, -\frac 2 3)$. The interpretation of this is that, if we call $a = (1, \, -\frac 1 3, -\frac 2 3)$, we have $M \cap N$ is the set of vectors of the form $k a$, for $k \in \mathbb{R}$, which is precisely what it means for it to be generated by $a$.

Edit: As requested, clarification for the system equivalence.

The method I used was (not quite) gaussian elimination. I say not quite because gaussian elimination would have gotten me the results as a function of $x_3$ and not $x_1$. Regardless, I will outline the method of (proper) gaussian elimination, and leave it to the reader to revise the above proof to work with $x_3$. One should end up with a different vector than above, and I encourage the reader to interpret why both vectors work.

The system we begin with is as follows:

$x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$

We wish to get rid of the first variable in the second line. As such, we subtract the first line from the second, yielding

$x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$

$2 x_2 - x_3 = 0$

Now, to get rid of the second variable in the first equation, we add half the second equation to the first. This gets us to

$x_1 + \frac 3 2 x_3 = 0$

$2 x_2 - x_3 = 0$

From this, one may write $x_1$ and $x_2$ as a function of $x_3$, and the rest follows.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Can you walk me through how you get the second equivalent system? You say that the system of equations can be easily shown to be equivalent, what process did you do? My linear algebra is rusty so I think that is why it's not as apparent to me

Comment: I edited my post to outline the algorithm. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will let you know if I have any questions about your suggestions added in the post

Comment: is it enough to add $x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$ and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ together? Then the vector $2x_1 + 3x_3 = 0$ would be in $M\cap N$ because $2x_1 + 3x_3$ still equals 0 right?

Comment: Be careful not to lose information. Yes, $2 x_1 + 3 x_3 = 0$, but be careful that you keep two equations. There are vectors that satisfy this but are not in $M \cap N$, for example, $(3, 2, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

A nonzero vector means that at least one of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ is not zero. The zero vector has all components equal to $0$. You simply need to solve the system of equations
$$x_1-x_2+2x_3=0$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=0$$
 to find such a vector. This will also help you show that all solutions are scalar multiples.